# How does lpp() deal with points that don't fall exactly on a segment?

Tags: r, gis, spatstat

If the coordinates of a point do not fall exactly on a line segment in a [linnet object](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/spatstat/versions/1.63-0/topics/linnet), how does [lpp()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/spatstat/versions/1.63-3/topics/lpp) handle that point?

Does it get dropped? Or snapped to the nearest segment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is “snapped” (projected) to the nearest segment **no matter how far away this is**.
Thus you should probably prepare your data with some more steps before calling `lpp`.
Below is a simple example which you could try to mimick if all your points
are in a `ppp` called `X` and the main component of your `linnet` is called L.
Of course you need to adapt distance thresholds etc. but hopefully it helps you
in the right direction.

```r
library(spatstat)

set.seed(42)
X <- runifpoint(10)
L <- simplenet

proj <- project2segment(X, as.psp(L))
i <- which(proj$d<.05)
Xclose <- X[i]
Xfinal <- lpp(Xclose, simplenet)

plot(L)
plot(X, add = TRUE, col = "red")
plot(Xclose, add = TRUE, pch = 2, col = "blue")
```

[image]

```r
plot(Xfinal)
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, exactly the clarification I needed. And thanks for the example on how to data prep!